# Cannot change Dropdown button value Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, drop-down-menu, dropdownbutton

I want to get the initial value of the Dropdown button from firebase;
but when I try to set the `governorateDDValue = selectedUser.governorate;` inside the build method
the value of Dropdown get the value from firebase but I cannot change it

[DropdownButton.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW7L2.gif)

this my code

```
class UserInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/UserInfoScreen';

  const UserInfo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserInfoState createState() => _UserInfoState();
}

class _UserInfoState extends State<UserInfo> {

  late User selectedUser;
  final date = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now()).toString();

  var governorateDDValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final userList= Provider.of<List<User>>(context);
    final userID = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    selectedUser =
        userList.firstWhere((user) => user.id == userID);

    // this line makes dropdown value always equal to value from firestore
    governorateDDValue = selectedUser.governorate;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('report'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Governorate',),
                    Container(height: 5),
                    DropdownButton<String>(
                      value: governorateDDValue,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                      iconSize: 24,
                      elevation: 16,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          governorateDDValue = newValue!;
                        });
                      },
                      items: Constants.governoratesOfEgypt
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `governorateDDValue = selectedUser.governorate;` inside build widget so the Dropdown menu will reset its value every time you change it
the build widget will rebuild and the value of the dropdown will stay equal to the value from firebase
you should use `governorateDDValue = selectedUser.governorate;` outside the build widget
this code should work will

```
class UserInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/UserInfoScreen';

  const UserInfo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserInfoState createState() => _UserInfoState();
}

class _UserInfoState extends State<UserInfo> {

  var loading = false;

  late User selectedUser;
  final date = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now()).toString();

  var governorateDDValue;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loading = true;
    print('Future.delayed outside');
    print(loading);
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      governorateDDValue = selectedUser.governorate;
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userList = Provider.of<List<User>>(context);
    final userID = ModalRoute
        .of(context)!
        .settings
        .arguments as String;
    selectedUser =
        userList.firstWhere((user) => user.id == userID);

    // this line makes dropdown value always equal to value from firestore
    governorateDDValue = selectedUser.governorate;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('report'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Governorate',),
              Container(height: 5),
              DropdownButton<String>(
                value: governorateDDValue,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                iconSize: 24,
                elevation: 16,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    governorateDDValue = newValue!;
                  });
                },
                items: Constants.governoratesOfEgypt
                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cannot change it is because every time `setState` is called your `build` method is called. Therefore your value will always be set to  `governorateDDValue = selectedUser.governorate;` So to allow changes you should place this  `governorateDDValue = selectedUser.governorate;` in `iniState`

Or what you can do is like this so that it will only set it once

```dart
class UserInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/UserInfoScreen';

  const UserInfo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserInfoState createState() => _UserInfoState();
}

class _UserInfoState extends State<UserInfo> {

  late User selectedUser;
  final date = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
  bool initState = true; // ADD HERE
  var governorateDDValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final userList= Provider.of<List<User>>(context);
    final userID = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    selectedUser =
        userList.firstWhere((user) => user.id == userID);

    // this line makes dropdown value always equal to value from firestore
    if(initState){  // ADD HERE
    governorateDDValue = selectedUser.governorate; 
    initState = false;  // ADD HERE
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('report'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Governorate',),
                    Container(height: 5),
                    DropdownButton<String>(
                      value: governorateDDValue,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                      iconSize: 24,
                      elevation: 16,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          governorateDDValue = newValue!;
                        });
                      },
                      items: Constants.governoratesOfEgypt
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: I  placed this  governorateDDValue = selectedUser.governorate; in iniState
it gives me this error LateInitializationError: Field 'selectedUser' has not been initialized.

when I remove "selectedUser =
        userList.firstWhere((user) => user.id == userID);" to initState 
it gives me another error
The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ModalScopeStatus>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _UserInfoState.initState() completed.

Comment: You have to move all your logic into iniState, if you need context for your provider you can use `didChangeDependencies`

Comment: I have edited the answer for a easier solution